# FaceDetector Not working after updated the google Play services to latest version(10.5.42)

Tags: android, google-play-services, face-detection

Face detector was running good with earlier play services versions in Moto X (2nd generation). After updating the play services version to latest (10.5.42), the detector stops working and getting the below warning:

Face detector dependencies are not yet available.

The detector is not operational after updating the play services. But it is working when I install the play services APK (10.2.91), is it a bug with the latest Play services APK? How this can be fixed?

Comment: isnt 10.5 the beta?

Comment: As @tyczj said, maybe you're getting an error because you're only using a beta version. Try updating to the [latest version 10.5.48](https://www.googleplayservicesapk.com/google-play-services-apk-10-5-48-update-latest-version-free-download/).